# Given “a player” as antecedent, when should the pronoun be “he” or “she”?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, gender-neutral, generic-they, antecedents

I am learning game theory. I always see that professors write (in text books):

- a player chooses her strategy
- If she chooses a strategy

Also some professors use *he* instead of *she*.

There other names also like *player*, but I forgot about them now.

How can I know when to use *she* versus when to use *he* in these situations?

Comment: Game theory is mathematics. Mathematicians, as Goethe once observed, "are like Frenchmen; whatever you say to them they translate into their own language, and forthwith it is something entirely different." Consider the ideal game player: the ideal game player has human intelligence and a consistent desire to win in a game. Nothing else is necessary, so gender is optional and can be assigned any available constant without loss of generality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an area where English is transitioning. Until thirty or forty years ago, almost every writer wrote *he* in this sense, without thinking any further about it.

Now, there is no generally accepted answer. If you write *he*, some will complain that females are being ignored or excluded. If you write *he/she* the result is ugly or unwieldy.

I prefer *they*, which has been used in this sense for centuries, but some people object to it.

Some writers use *she*, or use both *he* and *she* either alternately or at random.

A few writers have tried to popularise neologisms such as *ze*.

As I say, there is no generally accepted solution to the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the singular common gender usage of *they*, *them* to an English learner, but only because some people object to it without understanding why it's valid.

Comment: As long as they [learn the correct rule](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf) -- "Use singular _they_ **only** for nonspecific indefinite referents" -- they'll just sound like natives. If that bothers the ignorant, it's nothing new and can't be avoided in any case.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I also use singular _they_ for specific referents whose gender is unknown.

Comment: @JohnLawler Or specific referents whose gender is non-binary. (This topic has received *massive* coverage since you wrote that article in 2005, and it’s really rocking the *singular they* boat, it seems. I recall several style guides changing their views on it in recent years.)

Comment: @Lynn: Yeah, that one's a new addendum and hasn't had time to age properly yet. I predict it will either be avoided, or if not, it will find a set of comfortable contexts and disappear from notice.